# How to Create a SQL Credential in a local U-SQL database

Tags: azure, external, credentials

The CREATE CREDENTIAL U-SQL command is now depreciated, and the PowerShell command New-AzureRmDataLakeAnalyticsCatalogCredential has taken over. How to create a credential in a local u-sql database with the new Powershell command? I'm developing all my U-SQL stuff in Visual Studio and want to connect to an Azure SQL Database from my local environment. Possible?

Answer (score 1):

I needed this for my current tests that I am doing and after quite some investigations, I came up with a solution:

1. Find the location where the "LocalRunHelper.exe" is located
2. Run a command prompt window at that location
3. Replace the keywords and run the command:

   > LocalRunHelper.exe credential -DataRoot
   >   *{Absolute_path_of_local_u-sql}*
   >   -Add *{database}{credential_name}* -User *{sql_user}* -Password *{sql_password}* -Uri *tcp://{server}.database.windows.net:1433*

That's it!